# Grails Adding two columns in and condition

Tags: grails

I have two tables and need to write the following query in grails for tables having one to many relation.

table `Recipe` with columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`
table `Ingredient` with columns `a`, `f`, `g`, `h`

I need to write this SQL in Grails.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM recipe r
WHERE c+d NOT IN (SELECT g FROM Ingredient)
```

How do we combine columns `c`, `d` in where condition from `Recipe` table in Grails?

Answer (score 0):

So you do not write sql in grails.  Grails uses a groovy abstraction / implementation of hibernate which is called GORM:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#GORM

The section on "Many-to-one and one-to-one" will describe how to model you data correctly.

To make the query you may want to look at the where clause.

```
def query = Pet.where {
   owner.firstName == "Joe" || owner.firstName == "Fred" && type == "dog" 
} 
Pet joeOrFredsDog = query.find()
```

This type of query is documented here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/where.html